# When does ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush Actually Run Change Detection?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular 4 app with many components where the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` is `OnPush`. While [the Angular Documentation on the matter](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) is void of much information, various sources say that `OnPush` components only update when their `@Input`s change (new objects or primitives).

However, it seems that various events inside an `OnPush` component will also trigger change detection. I'm noticing others do not trigger change detection, however.

What are the specific rules for `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in regards to events inside a component?

Comment: this article will give you all the answers [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 5):

From [Change Detection Strategy: OnPush](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html),

> This will inform Angular that our component only depends on its inputs and that any object that is passed to it should be considered immutable.

It goes on to show that property changes don't trigger change detection (considered immutable), but changes to the object itself does trigger change detection.

So it looks like the key criteria is **immutability**. The change triggers for an object referenced on the template are,

- object ***reference*** change in code (either parent changes Input value ***or*** change within the child) ***will*** trigger change detection.
- object ***property*** changes from ***outside*** the component ***will not*** trigger change detection.
- object ***property*** changes from ***inside*** the component ***will*** trigger change detection.

I haven't tested a change from an observable, but that is given elsewhere as a trigger. (An observable emit changes an object reference, not it's properties).

Tested with angular version **5.2.0-beta.1**

---

**Extending the RangleIO example**

The RangleIO page referenced at the top of the post has a Plunker which illustrates that objects passed in to a component via `Input()` parameters are considered immutable. The change detector of the child component will not respond to changes of Input object properties.

However, after duplicating the change buttons ***inside*** the Movie component, it can be seen that object property changes invoked inside the component's own code will change it's view.

Here's the code, [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6P9H0HYGW662JtFFo1H6?p=preview)

**movie.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  styles: ['div {border: 1px solid black}'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
      <p>
        <label>Actor:</label>
        <span>{{actor.firstName}} {{actor.lastName}}</span>
      </p>
      <button type="button" (click)="changeActorProperties()">
        Inside Movie Component - Change Actor Properties (will change view)
      </button>
      <button type="button" (click)="changeActorObject()">
        Inside Movie Component - Change Actor Object (will change view)
      </button>
    </div>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MovieComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() actor: Actor;

  changeActorProperties(): void {
    this.actor.firstName = 'Nicholas';
    this.actor.lastName = 'Cage';
  }

  changeActorObject(): void {
    this.actor = new Actor('Bruce', 'Willis');
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>MovieApp</h1>
    <p>{{ slogan }}</p>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeActorProperties()">
      Outside Movie Component - Change Actor Properties (will not change Movie view)
    </button>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeActorObject()">
      Outside Movie Component - Change Actor Object (will change Movie view)
    </button>
    <app-movie [title]="title" [actor]="actor"></app-movie>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  slogan = 'Just movie information';
  title = 'Terminator 1';
  actor = new Actor('Arnold', 'Schwarzenegger');

  changeActorProperties(): void {
    this.actor.firstName = 'Nicholas';
    this.actor.lastName = 'Cage';
  }

  changeActorObject(): void {
    this.actor = new Actor('Bruce', 'Willis');
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer is _still_ not comprehensive enough. I'm finding new edge cases, so will try and give an exhaustive list shortly.

Answer (score 5):

[**This blog post**](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) of the [Angular University](https://angular-university.io/) contains several indications about the events that trigger change detection when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`:

> An OnPush change detector gets triggered in a couple of other
>   situations other than changes in component Input() references, it also
>   gets triggered for example:
>
> - if a component event handler gets triggered
> - if an observable linked to the template via the async pipe emits a new value

They add the following recommendations:

> So if we remember to subscribe to any observables as much as possible
>   using the async pipe at the level of the template, we get a couple of
>   advantages:
>
> - we will run into much less change detection issue using OnPush
> - we will
>     make it much easier to switch from the default change detection
>     strategy to OnPush later if we need to
> - Immutable data and @Input()
>     reference comparison is not the only way to achieve a high performant
>     UI with OnPush: the reactive approach is also an option to use OnPush
>     effectively

---

In [a comment](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/victorsavkinsblog/change_detection_in_angular_2/) following the question "Change Detection on Angular 2" on Disqus, Viktor Savkin explains:

> When using OnPush detectors, then the framework will check an OnPush
>   component when any of its input properties changes, when it fires an
>   event, or when an observable fires an event.